# How to fix connection between Report Server and ReportServer database

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

Power BI Web Service URL working, web portal URL isn't

I had to reinstall Power BI Report Server. I reconnected to the underlying Reportserver database. Since I didn't have a backup of the encryption key, I deleted encrypted content. At this point if I go to the web portal (http://reportserver/Reports) I get this error:

> "The service is not available. Contact your system administrator to
>   resolve the issue. System administrators: The report server can’t
>   connect to its database. Make sure the database is running and
>   accessible. You can also check the report server trace log for
>   details."

However when I go to the web service (http://reportserver/ReportServer), I can browse the report server directory. This information is coming from the underlying database so clearly the report server CAN connect to it's database. Both these happen both if I browse from my desktop or from the browser on the server itself. In the case of the server itself, I follow the links in the respective sections of the Admin tool, so links are correct, and Admin tool is indicating that web directory setup is correct.

Service restart does not help, neither does restart of the whole server. I also tried changing the name of the link (ie http://reportserver/PBIReports instead of http://reportserver/Reports) - still not working

Comment: By Admin tool, do you mean the Reporting Services Configuration Manager? Just making sure you checked that.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant!

Answer (score 0):

OK I found what was going on. The reason for the reinstall was to roll back from a newer version of Power BI server. Rollback was needed because it didn't play nicely with some other processes on the same server.
In any case... as per MS documentation, upgrade of Power BI server can trigger a (silent, background) update to the ReportServer structure. So after reinstalling the old version of Power BI, I was in fact trying to connect the old version of Power BI to a new version of the ReportServer Database.
Hopefully removing existing (upgraded) ReportServer Database and recreating it from the Config tool of the old version of Power BI Server will do the trick.